# How to create partial circle/arcs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Attaching with this a screen grab from strapfork.com. (If you scroll slightly below on the strapfork.com page, in the stats, you'll see circular arc the colored portion of which is in proportion to the number.) How to build a widget like that?

They are using some kind of javascript it seems but, I can't figure out how to replicate same.

[image: Image from strapfork]

Comment: Probably with the canvas element, SVG, or a combo.

Comment: Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/Moritur/FTqkG/4/

Comment: You can also refer to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter this looks good, but, it (the size of colored arc) needs to be in proportion to the percentage, is there a single number in the css which can be changed to make it proportional?

Comment: @GrishmaU You could try using the calc function to work out the angles of rotation based on percentage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc NOTE: I've never tried the calc functionality before so can't vouch for it's effectiveness.

Comment: Use SVG for graphical stuff like this. It can be done with pure HTML+CSS, but there are limits to what CSS can do; use SVG instead and you'll thank yourself later when you need to make a minor change that would be really difficult in CSS.

Comment: @Spudley Actually, I would prefer a javascript solution, HTML+CSS as you correctly pointed out has limits. SVG means I have to stop supporting ie8

Comment: Any solution (including SVG) would probably involve javascript as well. Most other options also mean dropping IE8 support. The best I can suggest is the [Raphael library](http://raphaeljs.com/), since that does use SVG but also supports old IE as well.

Comment: @Spudley Raphael library might just work, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Same as Spudley's comment : Raphael does the job and it works even on older browsers (IE7 ...)

A little bit of trigonometry and the Raphael Path object are what you need. Try the code below as an example:

HTML :

```
<div id="mytest"></div>
```

JS :

```
var paper = Raphael('mytest', 500, 400);

var background = paper.rect(0, 0, 500, 400, 0);
background.attr("fill", "#ffffff").attr("stroke", "none");

var centerX = 200, centerY = 200, Radius = 100, percent = 95;
// change the percent value between 0 and 100

var startArcX = centerX + Radius * Math.cos(Math.PI/2);
var startArcY = centerY - Radius * Math.sin(Math.PI/2);

var endArcX = Math.round(centerX + Radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * (0.5 - 0.02 * percent)));
var endArcY = Math.round(centerY - Radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * (0.5 - 0.02 * percent)));

var bigArc = (percent>50)?1:0;

var directionDrawing = 1;

var stringPath = 'M' + startArcX.toString() + ',' + startArcY.toString() 
               + ' A' + Radius.toString() + ',' + Radius.toString() 
               + ' 0 '
               + bigArc.toString() + ',' + directionDrawing.toString() + ' '
               + endArcX.toString() + ',' + endArcY.toString();



var path1 = paper.path(stringPath);
path1.attr("stroke", "#ff0000").attr("stroke-width", "20px");
```