# CSS - Cut a sector out of background

Tags: html, css

I want to cut a sector out of background.

I searched the internet but found only solutions with solid-colored backgrounds.
Like this: [How to draw a circle sector in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css).
jsfiddle.net/holden321/5jfP9/

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. What is the purpose of the JSfiddle provided and how does it relate to the image posted.

Comment: you will not be able to do that in css, but you could use html5 canvas and composite modes.

Comment: To make you what is on the picture. (cut background of the inside div)

Comment: Then you cannot do that with CSS.

Comment: as Paulie said, no way to do that with CSS