# Create a percentage Circle with CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to create this:

[image]

Using CSS only (I know it's possible with js) and having cross browser compability?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Try googling your question's title.

Comment: Not sure why I got so many downvotes, but after searching online, I managed to find this: http://jsfiddle.net/WEYEp/ and it's different from what I am trying to do...

Comment: @Luka Downvote as, per the downvote mouseover, "this question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 15):

I've googled your same question and this solution (http://circle.firchow.net/) came first. It's all plain html and css:

```css
.rect-auto,.c100.p51 .slice,.c100.p52 .slice,.c100.p53 .slice,.c100.p54 .slice,.c100.p55 .slice,.c100.p56 .slice,.c100.p57 .slice,.c100.p58 .slice,.c100.p59 .slice,.c100.p60 .slice,.c100.p61 .slice,.c100.p62 .slice,.c100.p63 .slice,.c100.p64 .slice,.c100.p65 .slice,.c100.p66 .slice,.c100.p67 .slice,.c100.p68 .slice,.c100.p69 .slice,.c100.p70 .slice,.c100.p71 .slice,.c100.p72 .slice,.c100.p73 .slice,.c100.p74 .slice,.c100.p75 .slice,.c100.p76 .slice,.c100.p77 .slice,.c100.p78 .slice,.c100.p79 .slice,.c100.p80 .slice,.c100.p81 .slice,.c100.p82 .slice,.c100.p83 .slice,.c100.p84 .slice,.c100.p85 .slice,.c100.p86 .slice,.c100.p87 .slice,.c100.p88 .slice,.c100.p89 .slice,.c100.p90 .slice,.c100.p91 .slice,.c100.p92 .slice,.c100.p93 .slice,.c100.p94 .slice,.c100.p95 .slice,.c100.p96 .slice,.c100.p97 .slice,.c100.p98 .slice,.c100.p99 .slice,.c100.p100 .slice{clip:rect(auto, auto, auto, auto)}.pie,.c100 .bar,.c100.p51 .fill,.c100.p52 .fill,.c100.p53 .fill,.c100.p54 .fill,.c100.p55 .fill,.c100.p56 .fill,.c100.p57 .fill,.c100.p58 .fill,.c100.p59 .fill,.c100.p60 .fill,.c100.p61 .fill,.c100.p62 .fill,.c100.p63 .fill,.c100.p64 .fill,.c100.p65 .fill,.c100.p66 .fill,.c100.p67 .fill,.c100.p68 .fill,.c100.p69 .fill,.c100.p70 .fill,.c100.p71 .fill,.c100.p72 .fill,.c100.p73 .fill,.c100.p74 .fill,.c100.p75 .fill,.c100.p76 .fill,.c100.p77 .fill,.c100.p78 .fill,.c100.p79 .fill,.c100.p80 .fill,.c100.p81 .fill,.c100.p82 .fill,.c100.p83 .fill,.c100.p84 .fill,.c100.p85 .fill,.c100.p86 .fill,.c100.p87 .fill,.c100.p88 .fill,.c100.p89 .fill,.c100.p90 .fill,.c100.p91 .fill,.c100.p92 .fill,.c100.p93 .fill,.c100.p94 .fill,.c100.p95 .fill,.c100.p96 .fill,.c100.p97 .fill,.c100.p98 .fill,.c100.p99 .fill,.c100.p100 .fill{position:absolute;border:0.08em solid #307bbb;width:0.84em;height:0.84em;clip:rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);-webkit-border-radius:50%;-moz-border-radius:50%;-ms-border-radius:50%;-o-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);-ms-transform:rotate(0deg);-o-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}.pie-fill,.c100.p51 .bar:after,.c100.p51 .fill,.c100.p52 .bar:after,.c100.p52 .fill,.c100.p53 .bar:after,.c100.p53 .fill,.c100.p54 .bar:after,.c100.p54 .fill,.c100.p55 .bar:after,.c100.p55 .fill,.c100.p56 .bar:after,.c100.p56 .fill,.c100.p57 .bar:after,.c100.p57 .fill,.c100.p58 .bar:after,.c100.p58 .fill,.c100.p59 .bar:after,.c100.p59 .fill,.c100.p60 .bar:after,.c100.p60 .fill,.c100.p61 .bar:after,.c100.p61 .fill,.c100.p62 .bar:after,.c100.p62 .fill,.c100.p63 .bar:after,.c100.p63 .fill,.c100.p64 .bar:after,.c100.p64 .fill,.c100.p65 .bar:after,.c100.p65 .fill,.c100.p66 .bar:after,.c100.p66 .fill,.c100.p67 .bar:after,.c100.p67 .fill,.c100.p68 .bar:after,.c100.p68 .fill,.c100.p69 .bar:after,.c100.p69 .fill,.c100.p70 .bar:after,.c100.p70 .fill,.c100.p71 .bar:after,.c100.p71 .fill,.c100.p72 .bar:after,.c100.p72 .fill,.c100.p73 .bar:after,.c100.p73 .fill,.c100.p74 .bar:after,.c100.p74 .fill,.c100.p75 .bar:after,.c100.p75 .fill,.c100.p76 .bar:after,.c100.p76 .fill,.c100.p77 .bar:after,.c100.p77 .fill,.c100.p78 .bar:after,.c100.p78 .fill,.c100.p79 .bar:after,.c100.p79 .fill,.c100.p80 .bar:after,.c100.p80 .fill,.c100.p81 .bar:after,.c100.p81 .fill,.c100.p82 .bar:after,.c100.p82 .fill,.c100.p83 .bar:after,.c100.p83 .fill,.c100.p84 .bar:after,.c100.p84 .fill,.c100.p85 .bar:after,.c100.p85 .fill,.c100.p86 .bar:after,.c100.p86 .fill,.c100.p87 .bar:after,.c100.p87 .fill,.c100.p88 .bar:after,.c100.p88 .fill,.c100.p89 .bar:after,.c100.p89 .fill,.c100.p90 .bar:after,.c100.p90 .fill,.c100.p91 .bar:after,.c100.p91 .fill,.c100.p92 .bar:after,.c100.p92 .fill,.c100.p93 .bar:after,.c100.p93 .fill,.c100.p94 .bar:after,.c100.p94 .fill,.c100.p95 .bar:after,.c100.p95 .fill,.c100.p96 .bar:after,.c100.p96 .fill,.c100.p97 .bar:after,.c100.p97 .fill,.c100.p98 .bar:after,.c100.p98 .fill,.c100.p99 .bar:after,.c100.p99 .fill,.c100.p100 .bar:after,.c100.p100 .fill{-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);-moz-transform:rotate(180deg);-ms-transform:rotate(180deg);-o-transform:rotate(180deg);transform:rotate(180deg)}.c100{position:relative;font-size:120px;width:1em;height:1em;-webkit-border-radius:50%;-moz-border-radius:50%;-ms-border-radius:50%;-o-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;float:left;margin:0 0.1em 0.1em 0;background-color:#cccccc}.c100 *,.c100 *:before,.c100 *:after{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}.c100.center{float:none;margin:0 auto}.c100.big{font-size:240px}.c100.small{font-size:80px}.c100 > span{position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:1;left:0;top:0;width:5em;line-height:5em;font-size:0.2em;color:#cccccc;display:block;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;-webkit-transition-property:all;-moz-transition-property:all;-o-transition-property:all;transition-property:all;-webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;-moz-transition-duration:0.2s;-o-transition-duration:0.2s;transition-duration:0.2s;-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-moz-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-o-transition-timing-function:ease-out;transition-timing-function:ease-out}.c100:after{position:absolute;top:0.08em;left:0.08em;display:block;content:" ";-webkit-border-radius:50%;-moz-border-radius:50%;-ms-border-radius:50%;-o-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;background-color:whitesmoke;width:0.84em;height:0.84em;-webkit-transition-property:all;-moz-transition-property:all;-o-transition-property:all;transition-property:all;-webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;-moz-transition-duration:0.2s;-o-transition-duration:0.2s;transition-duration:0.2s;-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in;-moz-transition-timing-function:ease-in;-o-transition-timing-function:ease-in;transition-timing-function:ease-in}.c100 .slice{position:absolute;width:1em;height:1em;clip:rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em)}.c100.p1 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(3.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(3.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(3.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(3.6deg);transform:rotate(3.6deg)}.c100.p2 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(7.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(7.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(7.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(7.2deg);transform:rotate(7.2deg)}.c100.p3 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(10.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(10.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(10.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(10.8deg);transform:rotate(10.8deg)}.c100.p4 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(14.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(14.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(14.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(14.4deg);transform:rotate(14.4deg)}.c100.p5 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(18deg);-moz-transform:rotate(18deg);-ms-transform:rotate(18deg);-o-transform:rotate(18deg);transform:rotate(18deg)}.c100.p6 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(21.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(21.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(21.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(21.6deg);transform:rotate(21.6deg)}.c100.p7 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(25.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(25.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(25.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(25.2deg);transform:rotate(25.2deg)}.c100.p8 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(28.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(28.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(28.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(28.8deg);transform:rotate(28.8deg)}.c100.p9 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(32.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(32.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(32.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(32.4deg);transform:rotate(32.4deg)}.c100.p10 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(36deg);-moz-transform:rotate(36deg);-ms-transform:rotate(36deg);-o-transform:rotate(36deg);transform:rotate(36deg)}.c100.p11 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(39.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(39.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(39.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(39.6deg);transform:rotate(39.6deg)}.c100.p12 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(43.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(43.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(43.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(43.2deg);transform:rotate(43.2deg)}.c100.p13 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(46.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(46.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(46.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(46.8deg);transform:rotate(46.8deg)}.c100.p14 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(50.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(50.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(50.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(50.4deg);transform:rotate(50.4deg)}.c100.p15 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(54deg);-moz-transform:rotate(54deg);-ms-transform:rotate(54deg);-o-transform:rotate(54deg);transform:rotate(54deg)}.c100.p16 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(57.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(57.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(57.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(57.6deg);transform:rotate(57.6deg)}.c100.p17 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(61.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(61.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(61.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(61.2deg);transform:rotate(61.2deg)}.c100.p18 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(64.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(64.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(64.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(64.8deg);transform:rotate(64.8deg)}.c100.p19 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(68.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(68.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(68.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(68.4deg);transform:rotate(68.4deg)}.c100.p20 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(72deg);-moz-transform:rotate(72deg);-ms-transform:rotate(72deg);-o-transform:rotate(72deg);transform:rotate(72deg)}.c100.p21 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(75.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(75.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(75.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(75.6deg);transform:rotate(75.6deg)}.c100.p22 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(79.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(79.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(79.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(79.2deg);transform:rotate(79.2deg)}.c100.p23 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(82.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(82.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(82.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(82.8deg);transform:rotate(82.8deg)}.c100.p24 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(86.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(86.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(86.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(86.4deg);transform:rotate(86.4deg)}.c100.p25 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);-o-transform:rotate(90deg);transform:rotate(90deg)}.c100.p26 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(93.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(93.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(93.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(93.6deg);transform:rotate(93.6deg)}.c100.p27 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(97.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(97.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(97.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(97.2deg);transform:rotate(97.2deg)}.c100.p28 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(100.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(100.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(100.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(100.8deg);transform:rotate(100.8deg)}.c100.p29 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(104.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(104.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(104.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(104.4deg);transform:rotate(104.4deg)}.c100.p30 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(108deg);-moz-transform:rotate(108deg);-ms-transform:rotate(108deg);-o-transform:rotate(108deg);transform:rotate(108deg)}.c100.p31 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(111.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(111.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(111.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(111.6deg);transform:rotate(111.6deg)}.c100.p32 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(115.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(115.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(115.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(115.2deg);transform:rotate(115.2deg)}.c100.p33 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(118.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(118.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(118.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(118.8deg);transform:rotate(118.8deg)}.c100.p34 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(122.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(122.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(122.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(122.4deg);transform:rotate(122.4deg)}.c100.p35 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(126deg);-moz-transform:rotate(126deg);-ms-transform:rotate(126deg);-o-transform:rotate(126deg);transform:rotate(126deg)}.c100.p36 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(129.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(129.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(129.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(129.6deg);transform:rotate(129.6deg)}.c100.p37 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(133.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(133.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(133.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(133.2deg);transform:rotate(133.2deg)}.c100.p38 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(136.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(136.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(136.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(136.8deg);transform:rotate(136.8deg)}.c100.p39 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(140.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(140.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(140.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(140.4deg);transform:rotate(140.4deg)}.c100.p40 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(144deg);-moz-transform:rotate(144deg);-ms-transform:rotate(144deg);-o-transform:rotate(144deg);transform:rotate(144deg)}.c100.p41 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(147.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(147.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(147.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(147.6deg);transform:rotate(147.6deg)}.c100.p42 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(151.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(151.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(151.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(151.2deg);transform:rotate(151.2deg)}.c100.p43 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(154.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(154.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(154.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(154.8deg);transform:rotate(154.8deg)}.c100.p44 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(158.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(158.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(158.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(158.4deg);transform:rotate(158.4deg)}.c100.p45 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(162deg);-moz-transform:rotate(162deg);-ms-transform:rotate(162deg);-o-transform:rotate(162deg);transform:rotate(162deg)}.c100.p46 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(165.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(165.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(165.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(165.6deg);transform:rotate(165.6deg)}.c100.p47 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(169.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(169.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(169.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(169.2deg);transform:rotate(169.2deg)}.c100.p48 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(172.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(172.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(172.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(172.8deg);transform:rotate(172.8deg)}.c100.p49 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(176.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(176.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(176.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(176.4deg);transform:rotate(176.4deg)}.c100.p50 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);-moz-transform:rotate(180deg);-ms-transform:rotate(180deg);-o-transform:rotate(180deg);transform:rotate(180deg)}.c100.p51 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(183.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(183.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(183.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(183.6deg);transform:rotate(183.6deg)}.c100.p52 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(187.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(187.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(187.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(187.2deg);transform:rotate(187.2deg)}.c100.p53 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(190.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(190.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(190.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(190.8deg);transform:rotate(190.8deg)}.c100.p54 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(194.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(194.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(194.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(194.4deg);transform:rotate(194.4deg)}.c100.p55 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(198deg);-moz-transform:rotate(198deg);-ms-transform:rotate(198deg);-o-transform:rotate(198deg);transform:rotate(198deg)}.c100.p56 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(201.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(201.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(201.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(201.6deg);transform:rotate(201.6deg)}.c100.p57 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(205.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(205.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(205.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(205.2deg);transform:rotate(205.2deg)}.c100.p58 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(208.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(208.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(208.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(208.8deg);transform:rotate(208.8deg)}.c100.p59 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(212.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(212.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(212.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(212.4deg);transform:rotate(212.4deg)}.c100.p60 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(216deg);-moz-transform:rotate(216deg);-ms-transform:rotate(216deg);-o-transform:rotate(216deg);transform:rotate(216deg)}.c100.p61 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(219.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(219.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(219.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(219.6deg);transform:rotate(219.6deg)}.c100.p62 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(223.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(223.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(223.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(223.2deg);transform:rotate(223.2deg)}.c100.p63 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(226.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(226.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(226.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(226.8deg);transform:rotate(226.8deg)}.c100.p64 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(230.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(230.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(230.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(230.4deg);transform:rotate(230.4deg)}.c100.p65 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(234deg);-moz-transform:rotate(234deg);-ms-transform:rotate(234deg);-o-transform:rotate(234deg);transform:rotate(234deg)}.c100.p66 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(237.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(237.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(237.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(237.6deg);transform:rotate(237.6deg)}.c100.p67 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(241.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(241.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(241.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(241.2deg);transform:rotate(241.2deg)}.c100.p68 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(244.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(244.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(244.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(244.8deg);transform:rotate(244.8deg)}.c100.p69 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(248.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(248.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(248.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(248.4deg);transform:rotate(248.4deg)}.c100.p70 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(252deg);-moz-transform:rotate(252deg);-ms-transform:rotate(252deg);-o-transform:rotate(252deg);transform:rotate(252deg)}.c100.p71 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(255.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(255.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(255.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(255.6deg);transform:rotate(255.6deg)}.c100.p72 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(259.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(259.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(259.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(259.2deg);transform:rotate(259.2deg)}.c100.p73 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(262.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(262.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(262.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(262.8deg);transform:rotate(262.8deg)}.c100.p74 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(266.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(266.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(266.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(266.4deg);transform:rotate(266.4deg)}.c100.p75 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);-moz-transform:rotate(270deg);-ms-transform:rotate(270deg);-o-transform:rotate(270deg);transform:rotate(270deg)}.c100.p76 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(273.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(273.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(273.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(273.6deg);transform:rotate(273.6deg)}.c100.p77 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(277.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(277.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(277.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(277.2deg);transform:rotate(277.2deg)}.c100.p78 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(280.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(280.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(280.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(280.8deg);transform:rotate(280.8deg)}.c100.p79 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(284.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(284.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(284.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(284.4deg);transform:rotate(284.4deg)}.c100.p80 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(288deg);-moz-transform:rotate(288deg);-ms-transform:rotate(288deg);-o-transform:rotate(288deg);transform:rotate(288deg)}.c100.p81 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(291.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(291.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(291.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(291.6deg);transform:rotate(291.6deg)}.c100.p82 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(295.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(295.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(295.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(295.2deg);transform:rotate(295.2deg)}.c100.p83 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(298.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(298.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(298.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(298.8deg);transform:rotate(298.8deg)}.c100.p84 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(302.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(302.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(302.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(302.4deg);transform:rotate(302.4deg)}.c100.p85 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(306deg);-moz-transform:rotate(306deg);-ms-transform:rotate(306deg);-o-transform:rotate(306deg);transform:rotate(306deg)}.c100.p86 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(309.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(309.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(309.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(309.6deg);transform:rotate(309.6deg)}.c100.p87 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(313.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(313.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(313.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(313.2deg);transform:rotate(313.2deg)}.c100.p88 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(316.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(316.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(316.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(316.8deg);transform:rotate(316.8deg)}.c100.p89 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(320.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(320.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(320.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(320.4deg);transform:rotate(320.4deg)}.c100.p90 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(324deg);-moz-transform:rotate(324deg);-ms-transform:rotate(324deg);-o-transform:rotate(324deg);transform:rotate(324deg)}.c100.p91 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(327.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(327.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(327.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(327.6deg);transform:rotate(327.6deg)}.c100.p92 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(331.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(331.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(331.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(331.2deg);transform:rotate(331.2deg)}.c100.p93 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(334.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(334.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(334.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(334.8deg);transform:rotate(334.8deg)}.c100.p94 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(338.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(338.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(338.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(338.4deg);transform:rotate(338.4deg)}.c100.p95 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(342deg);-moz-transform:rotate(342deg);-ms-transform:rotate(342deg);-o-transform:rotate(342deg);transform:rotate(342deg)}.c100.p96 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(345.6deg);-moz-transform:rotate(345.6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(345.6deg);-o-transform:rotate(345.6deg);transform:rotate(345.6deg)}.c100.p97 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(349.2deg);-moz-transform:rotate(349.2deg);-ms-transform:rotate(349.2deg);-o-transform:rotate(349.2deg);transform:rotate(349.2deg)}.c100.p98 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(352.8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(352.8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(352.8deg);-o-transform:rotate(352.8deg);transform:rotate(352.8deg)}.c100.p99 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(356.4deg);-moz-transform:rotate(356.4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(356.4deg);-o-transform:rotate(356.4deg);transform:rotate(356.4deg)}.c100.p100 .bar{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);-o-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}.c100:hover{cursor:default}.c100:hover > span{width:3.33em;line-height:3.33em;font-size:0.3em;color:#307bbb}.c100:hover:after{top:0.04em;left:0.04em;width:0.92em;height:0.92em}.c100.dark{background-color:#777777}.c100.dark .bar,.c100.dark .fill{border-color:#c6ff00 !important}.c100.dark > span{color:#777777}.c100.dark:after{background-color:#666666}.c100.dark:hover > span{color:#c6ff00}.c100.green .bar,.c100.green .fill{border-color:#4db53c !important}.c100.green:hover > span{color:#4db53c}.c100.green.dark .bar,.c100.green.dark .fill{border-color:#5fd400 !important}.c100.green.dark:hover > span{color:#5fd400}.c100.orange .bar,.c100.orange .fill{border-color:#dd9d22 !important}.c100.orange:hover > span{color:#dd9d22}.c100.orange.dark .bar,.c100.orange.dark .fill{border-color:#e08833 !important}.c100.orange.dark:hover > span{color:#e08833}
```

```html
<div class="c100 p34 center">
    <span>34%</span>
    <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you can change the percentage with a css class (`p34`).

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should post the CSS because of link-decay.

Answer (score 15):

There is also a good read on Medium on ["How to code a responsive circular percentage chart with SVG and CSS"](https://medium.com/@pppped/how-to-code-a-responsive-circular-percentage-chart-with-svg-and-css-3632f8cd7705).

It comes with a [code example](https://codepen.io/sergiopedercini/pen/jmKdbj/), too:

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.single-chart {
  width: 33%;
  justify-content: space-around ;
}

.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}

.circular-chart.orange .circle {
  stroke: #ff9f00;
}

.circular-chart.green .circle {
  stroke: #4CC790;
}

.circular-chart.blue .circle {
  stroke: #3c9ee5;
}

.percentage {
  fill: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="single-chart">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
      <path class="circle-bg"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <path class="circle"
        stroke-dasharray="30, 100"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">30%</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="single-chart">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart green">
      <path class="circle-bg"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <path class="circle"
        stroke-dasharray="60, 100"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">60%</text>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="single-chart">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart blue">
      <path class="circle-bg"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <path class="circle"
        stroke-dasharray="90, 100"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">90%</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code will have issues in some browsers (such as Chrome) due to using `viewbox` and not `viewBox`.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer and linking to the tutorial which really explained what the numbers in the SVG code meant. This allowed me to resize the progress circle fairly easily.

Comment: Can the animation begin only after scrolling down so it's in view? I don't want to animate it on page load if it is not above the fold.

Answer (score 5):

I really liked the gradient approach Sampson takes in his answer to this question: [How to draw a circle sector in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css)

Expanding it a bit using SCSS, I managed to create the following CSS-only solution:

```
/********* Circle Pie ***********/
$circle-diameter: 100px;
$circle-border-width: 10px;
$circle-background-color: #fff;
$circle-border-color-remaining: #ccc;
$circle-border-color-elapsed: red;

.pie {
  width: $circle-diameter;
  height: $circle-diameter;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: $circle-border-color-elapsed;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;

  &:after {
    display: none;
  }

  // Remove this if you do not need the percentage circle
  &:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: $circle-border-width;
    left: $circle-border-width;
    height: $circle-diameter - 2*$circle-border-width;
    width:  $circle-diameter - 2*$circle-border-width;
    line-height:  $circle-diameter - 2*$circle-border-width;
    background: $circle-background-color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
  }


  // loop to rotate first 50 percent
  @for $j from 1 through 50 {
    &.p#{$j} {
      background-image:
        /* 10% = 126deg = 90 + ( 360 * .1 ) */
        linear-gradient(90deg+(360*0.01*$j), transparent 50%, $circle-border-color-remaining 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, $circle-border-color-remaining 50%, transparent 50%); // remove highlight at the bottom half of the border/circle

      &:after {
        content: "#{$j}%";
      }
    }
  }
  // loop to rotate last 50 percent
  @for $j from 51 through 100 {
    &.p#{$j} {
      background-image:
        linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, $circle-border-color-elapsed 50%), // highlight the right half of the border/circle
        /* 90% = 54deg = -90 + (360*0.01*($j - 50) */
        linear-gradient(-90deg+(360*0.01*($j - 50)), transparent 50%, $circle-border-color-remaining 50%);

      &:after {
        content: "#{$j}%";
      }
    }
  }
}
/********* End Circle Pie ***********/
```

Then in your HTML you can use it like:

```
<div class="pie p63"></div>
```