# Progress bar view without rotating around does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, progress-bar

The following code is generating a circle bar by using canvas. Everything works fine.
But when I tried to change the code so that the percent circle and value view
dont rotate/circulate around until they reach the real position/value I run into
problems. The graph should only view the percentage position within the circle
and the value in the mittle of the circle without rotating/couting up to the real end value.
I know I have to change/delete some things in the JS arcMove() function like
deegres += 1 which is responsible for the rotation steps and so on, but if I tried it didnt work like it should.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      spanProcent = document.getElementById('procent'),
       c = can.getContext('2d');
 
  var posX = can.width / 2,
      posY = can.height / 2,
      fps = 1000 / 200,
      procent = 0,
      oneProcent = 360 / 100,
      result = oneProcent * 64;
  
  c.lineCap = 'round';
  arcMove();
  
  function arcMove(){
    var deegres = 0;
    var acrInterval = setInterval (function() {
      deegres += 1;
      c.clearRect( 0, 0, can.width, can.height );
      procent = deegres / oneProcent;

      spanProcent.innerHTML = procent.toFixed();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + 360) );
      c.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + deegres) );
      c.stroke();
      if( deegres >= result ) clearInterval(acrInterval);
    }, fps);
    
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
:root {
  background: #fff;
}

span#procent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #3949AB;
}

span#procent::after {
  content: '%';
}

.canvas-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <span id="procent"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the arcMove function you have to set degree to result so the interval is done on first call. But if you do not want an animation than you should use a pure css way of displaying it. Checkout the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41147560/8820118

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      spanProcent = document.getElementById('procent'),
       c = can.getContext('2d');
 
  var posX = can.width / 2,
      posY = can.height / 2,
      fps = 1000 / 200,
      procent = 0,
      oneProcent = 360 / 100,
      result = oneProcent * 64;
  
  c.lineCap = 'round';
  arcMove();
  
  function arcMove(){
    var deegres = result; // change degrees to result, than you won't have the animation.
    var acrInterval = setInterval (function() {
      deegres += 1;
      c.clearRect( 0, 0, can.width, can.height );
      procent = deegres / oneProcent;

      spanProcent.innerHTML = procent.toFixed();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + 360) );
      c.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + deegres) );
      c.stroke();
      if( deegres >= result ) clearInterval(acrInterval);
    }, fps);
    
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
:root {
  background: #fff;
}

span#procent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #3949AB;
}

span#procent::after {
  content: '%';
}

.canvas-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <span id="procent"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats it! Just a simple logic change, but unfortunately didnt catch it. Thanks a lot!