# HTML CSS circle slices aren't equal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a rainbow circle with 8 segments, 45 degrees in size.

You'll notice that the orange segment is double the size of the others.  I think these are number 1 and 8.  I can't however figure out how to separate them.  Are my degree wrong?

Thanks for your help.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pie {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: dashed 1px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 32em;
  height: 32em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}
.slice1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-22.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(22.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(67.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice4 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(112.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice5 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(157.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice6 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(202.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice7 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(247.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice8 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-67.5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.slice-contents1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffff4d;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice-contents2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9AC147;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice-contents3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #639b47;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice-contents4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3869c3;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice-contents5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1e3868;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice-contents6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #c682bb;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice-contents7 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9a1d34;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice-contents8 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f7941e;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.slice1 .slice2 .slice3 .slice4 .slice5 .slice6 .slice7 .slice8 .slice-contents1 .slice-contents2 .slice-contents3 .slice-contents4 .slice-contents5 .slice-contents6 .slice-contents7 .slice-contents8 {
  transform: skewY(40deg) rotate(25deg);
}
.slice-contents1:hover {
  background: #ffff1a;
}
.slice-contents2:hover {
  background: #8db23c;
}
.slice-contents3:hover {
  background: #588a3f;
}
.slice-contents4:hover {
  background: #2d549b;
}
.slice-contents5:hover {
  background: #132340;
}
.slice-contents6:hover {
  background: #ad4f9e;
}
.slice-contents7:hover {
  background: #85192d;
}
.slice-contents8:hover {
  background: #f38809;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>


  <ul class='pie'>
    <li class='slice1'>
      <div class='slice-contents1'>#</div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice2'>
      <div class='slice-contents2'>#</div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice3'>
      <div class='slice-contents3'>#</div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice4'>
      <div class='slice-contents4'>#</div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice5'>
      <div class='slice-contents5'>#</div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice6'>
      <div class='slice-contents6'>#</div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice7'>
      <div class='slice-contents7'>#</div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice8'>
      <div class='slice-contents8'>#</div>
    </li>


    <ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try it http://codepen.io/jonobr1/pen/ieFnh

Comment: or http://codepen.io/brbcoding/pen/mJkpf

Comment: Looks OK to me in firefox in the above codepen

Comment: @TIMINeutron im using chrome and the orange segment is 90degrees

Comment: http://codepen.io/Trumphouse/pen/qyuEb or try this

Comment: All your slices are 90degrees but are overlapping the others. The orange one seems to be on top.

Comment: @Doodlebunch where has slice1 gone? It should be yellow

Comment: [Are you after something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/tzh4Lp3L/)? Just change the percentages to match your needs (and you may want to add a white arc as circle 9 in the middle)

Comment: [With a white middle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzh4Lp3L/2/)

Comment: @Pete i'm not sure what's happened but the shapes are everywhere :P   i just want the yellow segment to appear.  is it anything to do with my z-index?

Comment: @Doodlebunch does this mean there'll always be one slice overlapping?

Comment: Ah sorry, I only tested in chrome.

Comment: @Pete i'm using chrome and its not working :/

Comment: [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/tzh4Lp3L/4/)

Comment: @Pete now i have a ranibow... :P

Comment: @Pete the circle should be like apple's loading icon

Comment: Ah right, you did say you were trying to create a rainbow circle

Comment: @Pete sorry, I can understand why I've been getting so many rainbows now.. :P

Comment: There's an interesting answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css

Comment: Ah, the problem was that you needed a 45% segment as your last segment so it wouldn't overlap the first segment - [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/tzh4Lp3L/6/)

Comment: @Pete but, any particular reason why red and orange share the same hover now?

Comment: I think it's because the segments are still quarters - if you inspect the elements it will show you the overlaps

Comment: @Pete and that red has a wonky line? :P

Comment: This version is a bit better but it has no transition on the hover and the hover on the orange is blocked by the yellow - http://jsfiddle.net/tzh4Lp3L/11/, your best bet may be to do a canvas or svg pie chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh thats obvious ... you are  using square element(li) and rotating it in different angles to make that pi..

According to your design each `li div` will be of `90 Degree` ,while `45 degree` of every will be hidden by other element,

for every element upto slices 7 will work good but slice 8  of angle=90.will cover yellow colored element.

take your fiddle for example ..you will notice only yours orange element(slice 8) is of 90 degree and rest are good except yellow(slice 1 ) that was hidden inside your slice 8.

to solve it you should reduce your arc to make it fit..

Make changes to following ..your pie will be go to go

```
.slice-contents8 {
position: absolute;
left: -100%;
width: 200%; height: 200%;
border-radius: 50%;

text-align: center;
transition: background-color .5s;
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, #f7941e 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.slice8 {
overflow: hidden; /**/
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: 0;
width: 50%; height: 50%;
transform-origin: 0% 100%; 
transform: rotate(-112.5deg); 
}
```

see the below demo 
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohxmoq1c/1/)

Comment: having same issue as above with the hovers not working

Comment: also, when i change the # on the html to a label, they've all moved to be covered by the following slice

Comment: changing it to label will create many new issues , what exactly you need to do, because if you are going to create pie chart its not the way to put label inside the arc...or you can create separate legends

Comment: because we was,fixing your need, and i was creating pie chart label in it i wll go for some other approach

Comment: i'll find another way for labelling :) still trying to get the red slice to highlight

Comment: any ideas about hovers on the red slice?