# How to draw a circle sector in CSS with a start and an end position (in deg)

Tags: html, css, geometry

I am trying to create a circle sector. This sector should be built in CSS by with a starting and an end positions measured in degrees.

For example: `startPosition: 155deg; endPosition: 245deg;`

[image]

I tried to find answer to this problem here:
[How to draw a circle sector in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css)

But none of the answers really helped me.

This is my code so far (http://jsfiddle.net/idoglik6/1mvgnsrc/):

```css
.pivot-control {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.pivot-control .pivot-container {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #2e3d5d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #bcd0e7;
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
}
.pivot-control .pivot-container .pivot-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.pivot-control .pivot-container .pivot-circle .pivot-hand {
  position: relative;
  background: #228ad5;
  height: 38px;
  left: 49%;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 2px #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="pivot-control">
  <div class="pivot-container">
    <div class="pivot-circle">
      <div class="pivot-hand" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? 
If you need to control the animation with a button, just put the animation rule in a separate class and toggle that one.

```css
.pivot-control {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.pivot-container {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #2e3d5d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #bcd0e7;
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
}

.pivot-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.pivot-hand {
  position: relative;
  background: #228ad5;
  height: 38px;
  left: 49%;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 2px #fafafa;
  animation: rotate-anim 3s;
  transform: rotate(245deg);
}

@keyframes rotate-anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(155deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(245deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pivot-control">
  <div class="pivot-container">
    <div class="pivot-circle">
      <div class="pivot-hand">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenooms/knL4sd3L/3/

Comment: Thanks. nice animation but i need to color the section (the pivot pass)

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1**
snippet here

```css
div {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    display: block;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;
}


.test {
        background-image:
      /*add 90 to 245deg to get the END point to  */
        linear-gradient(335deg, transparent 50%,  #bcd0e7 50%),
      /*add 90 to 155deg to get the START point to  */
        linear-gradient(245deg,  #bcd0e7 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

**OPTION2**

Snippet here

```css
div {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    display: block;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;
}


.test {
    background-image:
      /*subtract 155 from 90 to get the start point*/
        linear-gradient(65deg, transparent 50%,  #bcd0e7 50%),
       /*subtract 245 from 90 to get the end point*/
        linear-gradient(155deg,  #bcd0e7 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: nice! I tried to color the section between 30deg to 250 deg with your css Instructions, but unfortunately it did not color the right part.

Comment: .test {
        background-image:
      /*add 90 to 245deg to get the END point to 250  */
        linear-gradient(160deg, transparent 50%,  #bcd0e7 50%),
      /*add 90 to 300deg to get the START point to 30deg  */
        linear-gradient(300deg,  #bcd0e7 50%, transparent 50%);
}